# C++ STL string operator+ associativity

Tags: c++, operator-precedence, associativity

I tried out the following code in VC++ 2015

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int foo(int v)
{
    cout << v << endl;
    return 10;
}

string bar(int v)
{
    cout << v << endl;
    return "10";
}

int main()
{
    auto a = foo(1) + foo(2) + foo(3);
    auto b = bar(10) + bar(20) + bar(30);
    cout << "----" << endl << a << endl << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result on console is as follows

```
1
2
3
30
20
10
----
30
101010
```

As we all know, binary + operator has left-to-right associativity, and it can be confirmed by the 3 invocations to `foo`. They're called from left to right by instruction order.

My question is, why does this seem not hold for `string::operator+`? Have I got into some misunderstandings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confused between [associativity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and [order or evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified in C++. Associativity of `operator +` is left to right as you mentioned.

To understand this, try similar code snippet with `operator -`

---

From [Order or evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) (emphasis mine)

> Except where noted below, there is no concept of left-to-right or
>   right-to-left evaluation in C++. **This is not to be confused with
>   left-to-right and right-to-left associativity of operators**: the
>   expression f1() + f2() + f3() is parsed as (f1() + f2()) + f3() due to
>   left-to-right associativity of operator+, but the function call to f3
>   may be evaluated first, last, or between f1() or f2() at run time.

Answer (score 4):

You are assuming that the compiler emits code for the function call just before executing the addition operator. This is not necessarily true. The actual sequence of operations can simply be:

1. Call bar(30), save the result.
2. Call bar(20), save the result.
3. Call bar(10), save the result.
4. Add the results from step 3 and step 2.
5. Add the results from step 4 and step 1.

Of course, since addition is symmetric, the order of addition doesn't actually matter.

C++ does not require, in this case, the function call to occur immediately in conjunction with the addition. The rules governing the evaluation order are actually quite complex. Suffice to say that, in this case, the order of the function calls is not specified, and each C++ implementation can make the function calls in any relative order. In fact, the relative order can be different each time you run the program (rather unlikely of course, but this would still be compliant).